# How to get minimum length of a sublist from dictionary except zero?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a dictionary with list values, how can I get the number of elements where the value has a specific minimum length?

Below is my attempt:

```
mm = {1: [2, 5],
      2: [3, 4, 7], 
      3: [1, 4], 
      4: [], 
      5: [1], 
      6: [3, 4]}

item = min(mm, key=lambda f: len(mm[f]))
```

Expected output: `5`

Comment: Can you provide sample iinput and output ?

Comment: You already got the correct key from your code. Why not use that to get the value?

Comment: item = 5 is the output. @Rakesh 's answers works now

Comment: Sorry, expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just filter out the empty elements and pass the result to `min`:

```
item = min((key for key, value in mm.items() if value), key=lambda k: len(mm[k]))
```

The inner genexpr filters to only those keys where the value is truthy (non-empty), and `min` then operates only on those keys known to have non-empty values.

If you want the value itself, not the key that refers to it, this is even simpler:

```
min_non_empty_value = min(filter(None, mm.values()), key=len)
```

`filter(None` is an optimized case for discarding falsy values (empty `list`s in this case), and by removing the need to deal with/return a key, you can just use `key=len` directly to check the length of each value.

Answer (score -1):

This is one approach by checking if list is empty

**Ex:**

```
import sys

mm = {1: [2, 5],
      2: [3, 4, 7], 
      3: [1, 4], 
      4: [], 
      5: [1], 
      6: [3, 4]}

item = min(mm, key=lambda f: len(mm[f]) if mm[f] else sys.maxsize)
print(item) #5
```

Comment: Just for funsies, you could abbreviate the body of the `lambda` to `len(mm[f]) or sys.maxsize` and get the same result. Your way is more explicit, not *really* suggesting a change.

Comment: @ShadowRanger. Thanks that's a nice approach,  not think of that :).

Comment: @Rakesh ```if len(mm[f]) else``` works instead of just ```if mm[f] else``` but thanks

Comment: @Axel: You don't need to check the `len` twice; `if mm[f]` is faster and has the same effect (empty `list`s are just as falsy as the number `0`).

Comment: This will return `4` given input `{4: []}`, which seems incorrect. I would expect a `ValueError` exception instead, since there is no value satisfying the precondition.